# How to Do Soft Delete in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, postgresql

Hi I am new to Django and I have just completed  CRUD using django and postgresql.

now my aim is to do SOftDelete but I am unable to do it

below is my code

```
def Delemp(request,id):
    delemployee = EmpModel.objects.get(id=id)
    delemployee.delete()
    showdata=EmpModel.objects.all()
    return render(request,"Index.html",{"data":showdata})
```

I am unable to convert the function in such a way that It would perform softdelete instead of hard delete,please help

Answer (score 1):

Deletion in Django orm; By default, it like to hard delete. For soft delete you have to use a package or write your own manager class.

https://django-safedelete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ It is easy to implement in a Django project. I recommend. It provides hard-soft delete control with policies.

Comment: I tried import whats written in the link and it still didnt work

Comment: Did you install and migrate? And If you want softdelete data to show; Model.deleted_only.all() try. To see all data (including soft delete objects)  Model.all_with_deleted.all() @AmeyaPotdar

Answer (score 0):

In your case the soft delete doesn't work, since you don't use the object anymore. If it's still referenced, then it should work. Please look example from the links for details:

```
# Example of use

>>> article1 = Article(name='article1')
>>> article1.save()

>>> article2 = Article(name='article2')
>>> article2.save()

>>> order = Order(name='order')
>>> order.save()
>>> order.articles.add(article1)

# This **article will be masked**, but not deleted from the database as it is still referenced in an order.
>>> article1.delete()

# This **article will be deleted** from the database.
>>> article2.delete()
```